# Using $variable in PHP MySQL LIMIT

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, limit, offset

This is my current code which i'm using inside a php script.

```
$prodid = $_GET['id'];
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE productid = '$prodid' 
ORDER by amount DESC LIMIT 3");
```

I've set the LIMIT as 3. But I want to define something like '$count' and the value for $count should be fetched from a MySQL query i.e

```
$count = mysql_query("SELECT count FROM table1 WHERE productid = '$prodid'");
```

The LIMIT must change with respect to the '$prodid'. Like this,

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE productid = '$prodid' 
ORDER by amount DESC LIMIT '$count'");
```

Comment: Isn't it always going to be the number of records where productid = x? If count is equal to 10 and then you do the same query limit 10, why use it at all? It's going to be 10 records if you specify the limit or not.

Comment: First off, you're using mysql_ - a deprecated, insecure DB-handler. Use mysqli_ or PDO. Second, you're taking a user-defined variable, directly from an URL, and putting it into a query. Using mysql_query. Do you WANT your DB to be deleted? Lemme illustrate: https://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/exploits_of_a_mom.png

Comment: `LIMIT '$count'` => `LIMIT $count`. and make sure its an integer.

Comment: Listen to mkaatman above ... there's a logic error here; I can't conceive of any reason to put a limit statement in this query when the reality is that you want everything that's going to be returned anyway ...

Answer (score 1):

A few things.

**First**, you are using this query to find the number of rows to fetch.

```
 "SELECT count FROM table1 WHERE productid = '$prodid'"
```

That should say

```
 "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table1 WHERE productid = '$prodid'"
```

in order to get a count of rows.

And, it should say

```
 "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table1 WHERE productid = " . intval($prodid)
```

to avoid sql injection (assuming your `prodid` values are integers).

**Second**, the query above gives back a one-row result set. You need to actually read that row. I'm not going to tell you how to do that using `mysql_` because **only a fool uses `mysql_` these days.** Please, please use `PDO` or `mysqli_`.

**Third**, this query

```
"SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE productid = " . intval($prodid) . " ORDER by amount DESC"
```

*always* returns the number of rows your previous query wanted. So your `LIMIT` clause is entirely unnecessary in the example you've given.

Comment: Fine ! if count is a column name in the table1 and, there are different count values for each productid, like, for productid = 1, the count is 3 and for prodcutid = 2, the count is 6 and i want to fetch 3 results if $prodid = 1, similarly, 6 results if $prodid = 2.

How it can be queried ?